# How to create buttons and other images required for a project

Tags: java

Basically I am Java developer and I want to know how can I create buttons and other images required for my Java project.

As per my knowledge we will use photoshop for creating images.

But can anybody tell me exact process and any related videos or links showing how to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Oracle's [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) it should get you started in the right direction.

EDIT: As per your comment, you might want to take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/). As far as buttons and images are concerned, you just need to us the plain HTML tags. Also, if you are considering building an N-Tier Web Application you could consider taking a look at a framework such as [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework/) (tutorial [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/)). Spring should make some things easier.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here My project is web application and i cannot use the swing components. I want to use buttons and images in Jsp pages. Please suggest me How can i create buttons and images for Web application

Answer (score 0):

TRY **Synth** (Java 1.5 and above) .
This can convert the xml into Gui component. This is used for custom gui.

See this link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally Web developers uses the Adobe Photoshop and other Adobe tools for Creating the buttons and other images required for the project and finally they will come up with a **Prototype.**
                  Java Developers uses the the files(*.js,*.jpg...etc) created by the  web devlopers and they will write the business logic and DAO implementation.

Comment: The best way to know about the Photoshop is in Adobe Photshop CS3 we have Help Menu. In the Help Menu they mention all the concepts of Photoshop clearly.